# how would I make this script less laggy? lua

Tags: lua, obfuscation

So I am working on a obfuscator but when I add the string decoding algorithm it is really laggy because of this script:

```
local addEnc = ""
local shouldAdd = true
newScript:gsub(".", function(c)
    if c == ")" then
        if shouldAdd == true then
            addEnc = addEnc .. ")" .. MyAlgorithm
            shouldAdd = false
        else
            addEnc = addEnc .. c
        end
    else
        addEnc = addEnc .. c
    end
end)
```

It works fine with smaller script but when you obfuscate really large ones it takes ages.
So basically that script adds the decode algorithm after the first ) Is there any way to make this but not as laggy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going through the whole string, just to concat something after the first occurrence of `)`. You could use `newScript:find('%)')` to find the location of the first `)`, then simply concat the parts:

```lua
local index = newScript:find('%)')
return newScript:sub(1, index) .. MyAlgorithm .. newScript:sub(index + 1)
```

The `%` in `%)` is because is a special character in Lua string patterns. Alternatively, you can use `:find(')', 1, true)` to disable pattern matching and use a strict find.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed all of my performance issues :)

Comment: @cheatcentral Then don't forget to mark this answer as the solution to your question

Comment: should be `newScript:sub(1, index) .. MyAlgorithm .. newScript:sub(index + 1)`?

Comment: @Nifim Mhm now that you mention it, if you do want to keep the `)`, that's indeed what it should be.

Comment: I mean if you run your example with these inputs `(hello)!` and `world` you get `(hello)world(hello)!`

Comment: @Nifim Yes, meant to write `index + 1` but instead just wrote `1`. Good catch!

Answer (score 2):

You are using `gsub` for its standard purpose but in a very nonstandard way.

Rather than the function you can simply do:

```
newScript:gsub('%)', ')' .. MyAlgorithm, 1)
```

The 1 here prevents `gsub` from continuing to replace `)` with `")" .. MyAlgorithm`

---

Example

```
newScript = "((hello)!)"
MyAlgorithm = "world"

print(newScript:gsub('%)', ')' .. MyAlgorithm, 1))
```

Output

> ((hello)world!)

Comment: This works great tho my algorithm uses "%" and that removes all "%" for some reason, how would I fix that?